# passing filter to eva view

Tags: views, tokens

I watched the eva tutorial listed on the eva project page for drupal 7 and implemented that with our site. We have courses, objectives and evaluation content types. I am successfully able to attach all the evaluations to the course objective. The tutorial was great.

Since the evaluations are by semester, is there a way to add another filter by semester? I am so far unable to have the second contextual filter work on this eva view when the application is run. The 2nd contextual filter works within the view.

In the application there is a semester selection. We show all courses for that semester. Objectives for the course are displayed when the user clicks on a course. Objectives content type has entity reference to courses. Course objectives don't change by semesters, so in objectives content type there was no requirement to link to the semester taxonomy. Evaluations content type has node reference to objectives and entity reference to semester taxonomy.

I will really appreciate if someone can guide how to resolve the issue of a second contextual filter in eva view.